# How to pass a json array that comes from backend to child component using props and react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I'm doing a react js project and i'm having trouble passing an array of elements into a child component.

Here's my code:

**parent component**

```
{produtoFiltrado.map(produto =>
                        <div key={produto.id}>
                            <BoxProduto
                                arrayIngredientes={[produto.ingredientes]}
                            />
                        </div>
)}
```

this array is shown like this on my Insomnia request response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "ingredientes": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "nome": "Eucalyptus",
      "score": 10,
      "descricao": " ",
      "impacto": " ",
      "sinonimos": " "
    }
  ]
}
```

What i am trying to do is map this array in a child component, like this:

**child component**

```
{props.ingredientes.map(ingrediente => 
                                <ul key={props.ingredientes.id}>
                                    <ol >{props.ingredientes.nome}</ol>
                                </ul>
)}
```

(i'm using a functional component)

but this code is not working, I get the anwser that **"props.ingredientes" is undefined**

Why is it returning and undefined value? I used the same structure for passing strings and it worked just fine

Comment: `"ingredientes" !== "arrayIngredientes"`

Comment: ops, it's true! but i still get undefined!

Comment: Then please give a [mre].

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your request response is an array of objects as you are using .map in the parent component with the response. Lets say

```
produtoFiltrado = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "ingredientes": [
            {
            "id": 5,
            "nome": "Eucalyptus",
            "score": 10,
            "descricao": " ",
            "impacto": " ",
            "sinonimos": " "
            }
        ]
    },
    .....
    .....
    .....
]
```

You should do the following changes to your parent and child components

1. parent component

```js
{produtoFiltrado.map(produto => 
    <div key={produto.id}>
        <BoxProduto arrayIngredientes={produto.ingredientes} />
    </div>
)}
```

2. child component

```js
{props.arrayIngredientes.map(ingrediente => 
    <ul key={ingrediente.id}>
        <ol >{ingrediente.nome}</ol>
    </ul>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some changes that would fix your issues

```
// first add a check that `produtoFiltrado` is defined
{produtoFiltrado && produtoFiltrado.length && produtoFiltrado.map(produto =>
    <div key={produto.id}>
        <BoxProduto
                              // also remove the extra `[]` from your array
            arrayIngredientes={produto.ingredientes}
        />
    </div>
)}
```

Then in your child component also add a check before mapping

```
{props.arrayIngredientes && props.arrayIngredientes.length && props.arrayIngredientes.map(ingrediente => 
    <ul key={ingrediente.id}>
        <ol >{ingrediente.nome}</ol>
     </ul>
)}
```